# What are the alternatives to rotation methods in java

Tags: java, rotation, polygon

I am asked to create a program as following.. 
 "create random polygons, the point 
 when you press the mouse button is considered like a nail in the polygon. You can drag the polygon
with the mouse and place it somewhere on the wall. When you release the mouse button,
the polygon rotates around the nail in order to simulate the pulling of the gravity
You are not allowed to use methods from java (like AffineTransform). "
so far I managed to create random polygons, add a "nail", and drag the shapem but I can't seem to find a way to rotate it , can I -sort of- Transform it ?

Comment: This isn't clear; you need to rotate it, but you want to find "alternatives to rotation"?

Comment: You need to show work of what you have tried so far.

Comment: an alternative to the methods similar to AffineTransform)

Comment: One alternative is to write your own methods that do the math.

Comment: again such as such as rotation matrix?

Comment: What they want you to do is to 1) do some research on the mathematics of rotating shapes in 2-D, and 2) translate your understanding into Java code.  Hint: Wikipedia is a good place to look for topics like this!

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to using an `AffineTransform` is to use geometry to calculate the new polygon.

Comment: such as rotation matrix  ?

Comment: @user3126874 - Try it and see ...